# fread is storing binary backwards

Tags: c++, binary, endianness

I am trying to read an integer from a binary file, but am running into this problem where bytes are stored backwards, and so after interpretation (big-endian), it gives the wrong number.

Here is the first `4 bytes` of the binary file:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00100000
```

(an integer of value 32)

Here is my code to read these 4 bytes:

```
FILE *streamIn;
uint8_t boxSize[4];
...

    streamIn = fopen("Videos/special.mp4", "rb");
    size_t count = fread(boxSize, sizeof(uint8_t), 4, streamIn);
    unsigned int size = *(int *)boxSize;
    cout << "size : " << size << endl;

    uint8_t a = boxSize[3];
    std::bitset<8> x(a);
    std::cout << "x : " << x << endl;

    uint32_t b = size;
    std::bitset<32> y(b);
    std::cout << "y : " << y << endl;
```

This is the output:

**size : 536870912**

```
x : 00100000

y : 00100000000000000000000000000000
```

Why are the bytes being stored backwards in the variable *size*?

Also, if I change the code a bit and fread in 4byte intervals like below, I still get the exact same value for *size*:

```
    streamIn = fopen("Videos/special.mp4", "rb");
    size_t count = fread(boxSize, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, streamIn);
    unsigned int size = *(int *)boxSize;
```

Please help me understand why bytes are stored backwards into *size* with both methods.

Comment: Is this [big-endian/little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) related?

Comment: You are on a **little endian** system

Comment: Also, `*(int *)boxSize` will run afoul of strict aliasing rules. And possibly alignment rules.

Comment: You say bytes are "stored backwards", but backwards compared to what? The way you wish they were stored? What makes one way of storing bytes any better than the other?

Comment: On mp4 files, ints are stored big endian.

Comment: BTW when representing this kind of data consider using hexadecimal form, long binary strings are almost unreadable, hex is more usual and, most importantly, more compact.

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate of a question I saw once about endiannes, but I don't remember it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to decode big-endian data, do it manually:

```
constexpr inline uint32_t be_decode(const uint8_t* x) noexcept {
    return uint32_t(x[3] + x[2] * 0x100ULL + x[1] * 0x1'0000ULL + x[0] * 0x100'0000ULL);
}
```

That avoids the dangers of violating strict aliasing, mis-alignment, and different code for different byte-orders. Any useful optimizing compiler should be able to optimize it fully.

Comment: Hi @Deduplicator, could you please teach me how the code I presented will violate strict aliasing and mis-alignment? I would be super super thankful

Comment: An `uint8_t` has natural alignment of 1. A `uint32_t` has a natural alignment of 4 (or less if the CPU has a lower maximum alignment, which might be the case for 8bit and 16bit systems, think small embedded and micro-controllers, not somewhat current desktops). Thus, a properly aligned `uint8_t` obviously need not be properly aligned for a `uint32_t`. An array of `uint8_t` is not an `int`, thus treating it as one violates strict aliasing. Interestingly, the reverse is not true, as there is a deliberate exception.

Comment: Your function is error-prone. It accepts `const uint8_t* x` which might be an array with a different size than 4. This will cause undefined behaviour, segfaults, etc. Please change input parameter to `uint32_t`.

Comment: @DanielTrugman Why are you assuming you already have a `uint32_t` fully assembled though possibly mis-ordered lying about, considering it is read from a binary file?

Comment: Just like you read it from a binary file into a `uint8_t[]`, you can read it into a `uint32_t` using the wrong(!) endianess and then simply swap the byte order in place.

Comment: @DanielTrugman If you don't parse a whole block of bytes at once, but read individual objects one after the other, sure.

Comment: Hey, sorry one more noob question. Why do we multiply x[2] by 256 and not 16? I thought shifting binary values to the left by one position only doubled the value, there by multiplying by only 16 to shift it over by 8 positions. I know your code is right because I tested it, but I can't seem to understand why

Comment: @JohnPaoletto, because it is not 2*8, but rather 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2, which is 2^8.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are on a little-endian system, where the value of 32 is represented using:

```
00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Try doing the exact opposite (writing the value 32 to a file) using C code as well, and see what is written to the file:

```
uint32_t value = 32;
FILE *out = fopen("test", "wb");    
size_t count = fwrite(&value, 1, sizeof(value), out);
if (count != sizeof(value)) {
    printf("err");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Trugman, you're right, it's written the little-endian version of 32! I'm using Xcode on a Mac, never expected it to be a little-endian environment. So what would you recommend is my best course of action?

Comment: Is there a way to change my system to a big-endian system? If so, is that the best option?

Comment: Well... do you need you application to be compatible for both little and big-endian systems (i.e. ARM and Intel)? If so, you should make sure to convert all the values you are writing to the file to a specific endianess.